# OS X Terminal command to compact in tarball without compression

Tags: macos, terminal, tar

Is there a way to compact in tarball without compression using Terminal commands?

Comment: What do you mean by "compact... without compression"?  To create a tarball at the command line, just `tar cf something.tar file-a file-b file-c dir-d`  If you don't include one of the compression options (`-j`, `-z`, `-Z`...) the tarball will not be compressed.

Comment: At my work place we use Keka to compress and archive in tarball. I think you answered my question. The tarball files must weight the same as the folders, meaning that there is no compression. Many thanks! Cheers

Answer (score 0):

As user4556274 has commented, the command:

`tar cf /path/to/destination/something.tar file-a file-b file-c dir-d`

without the compression options (-j, -z, -Z...) will generate a tarball not compressed.

About the reason one would want to do this, let me give you a couple of examples:

- If you have to copy a lot (I mean **a lot**) of small files, and/or
  maybe many nested folders, the time to copy will not depend much on
  the actual total size, but rather on the number of files (this is
  because it is cumbersome for the cpu to copy the file system
  (allocation table), rather than the actual bytes.
- If some software need to indicize a volume, you also will have slow-downs if you have a lot of small files and/or nested folders.

In both cases, you want to create one single file, out of you collection of small files and/or nested folders. However, you are not really interested in saving space (the actual total size may be already small) and you don't want to spend time or computing power to compress the data.